# Finding an average when there is fake data

Tags: statistics, average

A reader $i$ reads $N_i$ articles per day (usually like 1-20). There are many (e.g. million) readers. Some minor number (e.g. 100 or 1000) of readers are fake. A fake reader reads many (e.g. 1000 or 10000) articles per day.

We pay readers.

So the obvious problem is to filter away fake readers. How to do this?

I'd find an average number $M$ of read articles per day and decrease $N_i$ to $3M$ if $N_i > 3M$ to pay only for $3M$ reads rather than to fake $N_i$ reads.

The main question is how could I calculate the average in such a way that fake readers would not distort the average much?

Comment: Sounds like an outlier elimination problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Definitions_and_detection

Comment: use the median, instead of the average

Comment: The trouble of course is that if you start not paying people who read vast numbers of articles, people will just reprogram their bots to only read 20 articles a day or something. They might even register several accounts and end up costing you as much money as before.

Comment: @JackM I took this into account: Registering several accounts is quite costly.

Comment: @porton But surely there are only two possibilities. Either the cost per-account is more than the typical amount made from reading, or it's less. If it's more, then nobody can make any money, and if it's less, with say a difference of $d$ dollars, then you make $d$ dollars per account and so making many accounts is still profitable.

Comment: @JackM No, because the cost of the account is dependent on the person who creates it.

Comment: @porton Okay, so for the purposes of this problem let's just say you can prevent people from registering several accounts.